# Git is getting stuck at 'Downloading from snapshots' step. How to solve it?

Tags: git, jenkins, artifactory

In my Jenkins, I have configured git to take the pull from artifactory, which sometimes gets stuck at  'Downloading from snapshots' step. And it takes complete 15 minutes gap to retry. Can I reduce this time so that it waits for only 1 minute and then retry?

Answer (score 2):

The Jenkins Git client have a property you can set for controlling the client timeout - `org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.Git.timeOut`. The property value should be the expected timeout in minutes (I suspect, it is not documented). The default value is 10m.
It is briefly mentioned in the Jenkins Git client plugin [change log](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Git+Client+Plugin).
In general, the Java process which starts Jenkins needs the argument, for example `-Dorg.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.Git.timeOut=5`

Comment: Did you see that the timeout configuration was applied in Jenkins (it should appear in the log)? what type of git command are you using - checkout, pull etc. ?

Comment: I added this command in apache tomcat's catalina.sh because I am running my jenkins with tomcat. I can see these parameters in tomcat logs, but still problem is same.